# Type inference failing when mapping withing a flatMap in state monad

Tags: scala, shapeless, scala-cats

#### overview

I'm trying to infer types of `cats.data.IndexedStateT[F[_], SA, SB, A]` passed in to the flatMap method. When just using flatMap, type inference seem to infer the type parameters for SA, SB and A correctly. However, when I use map within the flatMap it fails.

Is there a way to make this type inference work without manually specifying the type parameters for IndexedStateT passed into flatMap?

```scala
class X
class Y


// Type inference works well when just using flatMap
val res1: IndexedStateT[Eval, Unit, Y, Y] =
    IndexedStateT[Eval, Unit, X, X](_ => Eval.now(new X, new X))
      .flatMap { x =>
        IndexedStateT(_ => Eval.now(new Y, new Y)) // Infers IndexedStateT[Eval, X, Y, Y]
      }


// Type inference fails when mapping inside flatMap
val res2: IndexedStateT[Eval, Unit, Y, (X, Y)] =
    IndexedStateT[Eval, Unit, X, X](_ => Eval.now(new X, new X))
      .flatMap { x =>
        IndexedStateT(_ => Eval.now(new Y, new Y)).map(x -> _) // Fails to infer the types for IndexedStateT[Eval, X, Y, Y] "missing parameter type"
      }
```

#### Usage context

I'm using a specialised type of State monad in application code

```scala
type HListState[SA <: HList, A] = IndexedStateT[Eval, SA, A :: SA, A]
  object HListState {
    def apply[SA <: HList, A](fn: SA => A): HListState[SA, A] = IndexedStateT[Eval, SA, A :: SA, A](sa => Eval.now((fn(sa) :: sa, fn(sa))))
  }

// Type inference works here
val res3: IndexedStateT[Eval, HNil, Y :: X :: HNil, Y] =
  HListState[HNil, X](_ => new X).flatMap { x =>
    HListState(_ => new Y)
  }

// Inference not so good :(
val res4: IndexedStateT[Eval, HNil, Y :: X :: HNil, (X, Y)] = 
  HListState[HNil, X](_ => new X).flatMap { x =>
    HListState(_ => new Y).map(x -> _)  // <--- type inference fails here :( "missing parameter type"
  }
```

Is there a way to get the type inference working in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Without `map`, the compiler can use the expected type of `res1` to figure out type parameters of `flatMap` and so of `IndexedStateT`. But when you add `map`, there's no expected type for the `IndexedStateT` call.

I can't be sure without testing it, but I expect that specifying the parameter type (`SA`) should be enough, the rest should be inferred without problems:

```
IndexedStateT { _: X => Eval.now(new Y, new Y) }.map(x -> _)
```